# Creating external tables from Google Sheet in BigQuery Clould Shell using a sheet other than the default

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I am creating a BQ table from the second tab of a GoogleSheets spreadsheet. First, I create the table definition file as follows:

```
bq mkdef \
--noautodetect \
--source_format=source_format \
"drive_uri" \
path_to_schema_file > /tmp/mytable_def.json
```

and then I manually modify mytable_def.json to indicate that the table should be created from the second tab:

```
"googleSheetsOptions":{"range": "sheetB"}
```

However, I am looking for a way to do this directly from the first mkdef command. Is this possible?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it looks like you have the right / only approach to take.  I'm not seeing any other options out there unfortunately.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-table-definition#google_drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is worth trying [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) tool as reliable way to process JSON objects as a data manipulation step in the above mentioned approach:

```
bq mkdef \
--noautodetect \
--source_format=source_format \
"drive_uri" \
path_to_schema_file | jq '.googleSheetsOptions += {"range": "sheetB"}' > /tmp/mytable_def.json
```

As was mentioned by @Daniel Zagales, referencing the documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-table-definition#google_drive), table definition file should be adjusted by the hand or  substituted for any tool that can afford it as a part of command-line processing.